# Rotate Video Preview Layer according to Device orientation. Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, orientation

I have been trying to get my live video feed (camera Preview Layer) to rotate orientations when the device is rotated. I am completely stuck. I have provided my current code below.

Note: this app is an iMessage extension not a normal app.

My current code:

```
 func setupPreviewLayer() {
        cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
        orientationChange()
        cameraPreviewLayer?.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height / 2
        cameraPreviewLayer?.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width / 2
        liveVideoFeedPosition()
        cameraPreviewLayer?.position.x = self.view.frame.width / 2
        cameraPreviewLayer?.position.y = self.view.frame.height / 4  //- 33 original
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!)
    }
```

**Not consecutive

```
 func liveVideoFeedPosition() {
        if presentationStyle == MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle.compact {
            holoLogo.isHidden = true
            cameraPreviewLayer?.position.x = self.view.frame.width / 2
            cameraPreviewLayer?.position.y = self.view.frame.height / 4  //+33 original
        }
        if presentationStyle == MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle.expanded {
            holoLogo.isHidden = false
            cameraPreviewLayer?.position.x = self.view.frame.width / 2
            cameraPreviewLayer?.position.y = self.view.frame.height / 2  //- 27 original
        }
        self.OutlineImage.center.y = self.view.center.y // - 27 original
        self.OutlineImage.center.x = self.view.center.x
        self.view.addSubview(OutlineImage)
    }
```

**Not consecutive

```
 override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {

        if UIDevice.current.orientation == .portrait {
            captureSession.stopRunning()
            self.view.layer.sublayers?.removeAll()
            orientation = "Portrait"
            setupInputOutput()
            setupPreviewLayer()
            captureSession.startRunning()
        }
        if UIDevice.current.orientation == .portraitUpsideDown {
            captureSession.stopRunning()
            self.view.layer.sublayers?.removeAll()
            orientation = "Portrait UpsideDown"
            setupInputOutput()
            setupPreviewLayer()
            captureSession.startRunning()
        }

        if UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft {
            captureSession.stopRunning()
            self.view.layer.sublayers?.removeAll()
            orientation = "Landscape Left"
            setupInputOutput()
            setupPreviewLayer()
            captureSession.startRunning()
        }
        if UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeRight {
            captureSession.stopRunning()
            self.view.layer.sublayers?.removeAll()
            orientation = "Landscape Right"
            setupInputOutput()
            setupPreviewLayer()
            captureSession.startRunning()
        }
        liveVideoFeedPosition()
    }
```

**Not consecutive

```
var orientation = "Portrait"

    func orientationChange() {
        if orientation == "Portrait" {
            cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
        }
        if orientation == "Portrait UpsideDown" {
            cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .portraitUpsideDown
        }
        if orientation == "Landscape Right" {
            cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
        }
        if orientation == "Landscape Left" {
            cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeLeft
        }
    }
```

All this code is not ini a specific order.

Comment: I don't want to be rude or anything, but if you can't figure it out you could always try setting a specific orientation.

Comment: @E.Huckabee That was my original plan. Since it’s an iMessage extension, all orientations must be supported. If I set the orientation when the app first boots up it will work but, it will not change if the device is rotated. It’s like I can’t change it after I set it.

Comment: Sorry about that, didn’t catch the part about it being an iMessage extension. Ill look into it and see what I can do.